# change the color of links in networkD3 sankeyNetwork using R

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I have created a `sankeyNetwork` using [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) in [r](/questions/tagged/r). How can I change the color of flow lines or links? I would like to have the flow lines be the same color as the nodes.

Here is my code:

```
library(networkD3)
library(xlsx)
links <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Book1.xlsx", sheetName = "links")
nodes <- read.xlsx("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Book1.xlsx", sheetName = "nodes")

sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "Diagnosis", fontSize = 11, nodeWidth = 15, fontFamily = "arial", iterations = 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

No one here can reproduce your example because no one but you has access to the `Book1.xlsx` file that is on your Desktop (read more here about [making good reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4389763)). However, the help file for `sankeyNetwork()` (you can access it by typing `?sankeyNetwork` in the R console) documents the `LinkGroup` argument and gives an example of using it at the bottom.

> LinkGroup - character string specifying the groups in the Links. Used to color the links in the network.

```r
library(networkD3)

URL <- paste0('https://cdn.rawgit.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/',
              'master/JSONdata/energy.json')
energy <- jsonlite::fromJSON(URL)

energy$links$energy_type <- sub(' .*', '', energy$nodes[energy$links$source + 1, 'name'])


sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$links, Nodes = energy$nodes, Source = 'source',
              Target = 'target', Value = 'value', NodeID = 'name',
              LinkGroup = 'energy_type')
```

[image]